# HazelcastSerializationException: Problem while reading DataSerializable, namespace: 0, id: 0

Tags: hazelcast

I have a Tree domain object which I'm trying to process with Hazelcast's MapReduce in order to get its average diameter per species. I have no trouble getting the IList and populating it with trees, but when I send a Job to map, reduce and submit the result I get the error message from the title (it also reads "*exception: ...Tree.()*" at the end).

I'm using DataSerializable because it's what I was recommended to use for serialization instead of Java's Serializable. I tried using Serializable but I got another Exception:

> HazelcastSerializationException: java.io.InvalidClassException: ...Tree; class invalid for deserialization

Here's my domain object:

```
public class Tree implements DataSerializable {

private String neighbourhood;
private String street;
private String scientificName;
private Double diameter;

public Tree(String neighbourhood, String street, String scientificName, Double diameter) {
    this.neighbourhood = neighbourhood;
    this.street = street;
    this.scientificName = scientificName;
    this.diameter = diameter;
}

public Tree() {
    this.neighbourhood = "";
    this.street = "";
    this.scientificName = "";
    this.diameter = 0.0;
}

public String getNeighbourhood() {
    return neighbourhood;
}

public String getStreet() {
    return street;
}

public String getScientificName() {
    return scientificName;
}

public Double getDiameter() {
    return diameter;
}

@Override
public void writeData(ObjectDataOutput out) throws IOException {
    out.writeUTF(this.neighbourhood);
    out.writeUTF(this.street);
    out.writeUTF(this.scientificName);
    out.writeDouble(this.diameter);
}

@Override
public void readData(ObjectDataInput in) throws IOException {
    this.neighbourhood = in.readUTF();
    this.street = in.readUTF();
    this.scientificName = in.readUTF();
    this.diameter = in.readDouble();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Tree tree = (Tree) o;
    return neighbourhood.equals(tree.neighbourhood) &&
            street.equals(tree.street) &&
            scientificName.equals(tree.scientificName) &&
            diameter.equals(tree.diameter);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(neighbourhood, street, scientificName, diameter);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

MapReduce was [deprecated](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.12.10/manual/html-single/index.html#mapreduce) in Hazelcast 3.8 in 2017 and removed in Hazelcast 4. It was superceded by fast aggregations and Jet depending on the needed complexity. So it's not ideal to use MapReduce as you'll have to discard your code when you come to upgrade.

Your `Tree` class looks fine. You don't show your MapReduce code so I can't try it.

Does this work for you instead, using the replacement aggregations

```
        IMap<Integer, Tree> treesMap = hazelcastClient.getMap("trees");
        treesMap.set(1, new Tree("a", "a", "giant redwood", 1d));
        treesMap.set(2, new Tree("b", "b", "larch", 2d));
        treesMap.set(3, new Tree("c", "c", "fir", 3d));
        treesMap.set(4, new Tree("d", "d", "mighty scots pine", 4d));
        treesMap.set(5, new Tree("e", "e", "larch", 5d));

        Map<String, Double> results = treesMap.aggregate(new Aggregator<Map.Entry<Integer, Tree>, Map<String, Double>>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            
            protected final Map<String, Double> totals = new HashMap<>();
            protected final Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
            
            @Override
            public void accumulate(Entry<Integer, Tree> input) {
                counts.merge(input.getValue().getScientificName(), 1, Integer::sum);
                totals.merge(input.getValue().getScientificName(), input.getValue().getDiameter(), Double::sum);
            }

            @Override
            public void combine(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Aggregator aggregator) {
                Map<String, Integer> thatCounts = this.getClass().cast(aggregator).counts;
                thatCounts.entrySet().forEach(entry -> counts.merge(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), Integer::sum));
                Map<String, Double> thatTotals = this.getClass().cast(aggregator).totals;
                thatTotals.entrySet().forEach(entry -> totals.merge(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), Double::sum));
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, Double> aggregate() {
                final Map<String, Double> result = new HashMap<>();
                this.totals.keySet().forEach(key -> {
                    result.put(key, this.totals.get(key) / this.counts.get(key));
                });
                return result;
            }
        });

        results.entrySet().stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```